# What is the difference between the lua and the vimscript-lua tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have two tags: `vimscript-lua` and `lua`.

Looking at their descriptions and the question flagged they seems very similar:

- `Lua programming interface to Vim. DO NOT use for questions with Lua examples or about syntax highlighting in Lua.`
- `Question about the Lua binding in Neovim`

Maybe the intention of the first was to flag the Vim Lua binding like we could flag the Vim Python binding.

Maybe the intention of the second is only about the Neovim lua binding to the Neovim API.

I have the impression that the first is mostly or entirely miss-used for the second.

Should we merge them or have a synonym?

There is a family of questions of the kind:

> How to translate that from VimScript to Neovim/Lua?

I would be good to have a way to flag these question since it give access to examples for the users.

Which tags should we use for that is `lua` a good name for it?

Comment: Hm. Unclear. I’ll look myself, but my gut says to distinguish or merge

Comment: `lua` as a tag should not exist. It should either be `vimscript-lua` or `filetype-lua`. Possibly `neovim-lua` can also be added, but I'm not sure if it's all that useful.

Comment: Same with e.g. [tag:python] by the way, which should be either [tag:vimscript-python] or [tag:filetype-python]. But I gave up on all of this tagging stuff a long time ago because it's a never-ending cleanup and the tools the platform gives us are just not good enough.

Comment: @Martin There are a number of questions about lua conversion. Maybe it would be interesting for some to go through these questions to learn about conversion. At least that was the trigger of my question :-)